# TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro' discord.py having problems fixing

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So, I just started coding a discord bot in python. I've done this several times before, but when I tried to run the code this error message came up.

```
TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'
```

This is my code:

```
#import
import discord
import os

#client
client = discord.Client

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Best bot is online. ({0.user})'
    .format(client))

#commands
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('Ωhello'):
        await message.channel.send('responded Hello World!')

#run
client.run(os.getenv('token'))
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `client` variable is now just a reference to the `discord.Client` class, you need an **instance** of it.

```py
client = discord.Client  # This doesn't do much of anything
client = discord.Client(here, be, arguments)  # This creates an instance of a class
```

Comment: Alright, now what? What arguments should I add? I can't add client = discord.Client(coro), because if I do that, I get this error message: NameError: name 'coro' is not defined

Comment: Why would you pass a coroutine into that...? Read the docs to see what arguments you can give to it, or look at the official examples. You can't just randomly put a word in there somewhere and hope it works... you'll get nowhere that way. Before using a function, _read_ what the arguments actually _are_. In this case you're using `coro` which is a variable you never created. `Client` doesn't even take a coroutine as an argument....... Official quickstart example from the docs: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot

Answer (score 0):

The way you are defining your client is what is causing this error. Here is a popular example of how clients are set up using discord.py:

```
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your prefix', intents=discord.Intents.all()) # you'll need to import commands from discord.ext
```

Hope this helps